# How Can I Enable Sorting/Filtering on XSSFTable Columns Using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf, excel-tables

I'm working on an application that fetches database records and creates an excel doc from that data.

The excel doc is generated fine and all the data is readable; as of a previous answer from this forum the table is also appropriately generated (the header row remains visible even when I've scrolled past it, so the table is definitely present). However, I had expected that once I had a table I'd be able to sort and filter the columns as is the case when you 'Insert -> Table' in excel, but there are no such options when I open the doc.

I don't see a setFitlerable or setSortable or anything like that on the XSSFTable or XSSFTableColumn classes... How do I enable sorting/filtering on the table columns?

Table creation code follows, if it's useful:

```
//Create table
CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(sheet.getRow(3).getCell(0));
CellReference bottomRight = new CellReference(sheet.getRow(nextRow-1).getCell(3));
AreaReference tableArea = workbook.getCreationHelper().createAreaReference(topLeft, bottomRight);
XSSFTable dataTable = sheet.createTable(tableArea);

dataTable.setName("TableData" + EXCEL_OBJECT_NUMBER);
dataTable.setDisplayName("TableData" + EXCEL_OBJECT_NUMBER);

XSSFTableColumn column = dataTable.getColumns().get(0);
column.setId(1);
column.setName("COLUMN1");

column = dataTable.getColumns().get(1);
column.setId(2);
column.setName("COLUMN2");

column = dataTable.getColumns().get(2);
column.setId(3);
column.setName("COLUMN3");

column = dataTable.getColumns().get(3);
column.setId(4);
column.setName("COLUMN4");
```

Comment: I smelled that follow up question. So that all was already in my complete example code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315130/how-do-i-convert-an-area-in-an-excel-doc-to-a-table-using-apache-poi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `dataTable` is a `XSSFTable` and `tableArea` is the `AreaReference` of that `XSSFTable`, then the following code sets the auto filters into the table headers as `Excel` also does it:

```
dataTable.getCTTable().addNewAutoFilter().setRef(tableArea.formatAsString());
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreateExcelTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
   new Object[] {"Text", "Date", "Number", "Boolean"},
   new Object[] {"Text 1", new GregorianCalendar(2020, 0, 1), 1234d, true},
   new Object[] {"Text 2", new GregorianCalendar(2020, 1, 15), 5678d, true},
   new Object[] {"Text 3", new GregorianCalendar(2020, 2, 1), 90.1234, false},
   new Object[] {"Text 4", new GregorianCalendar(2020, 3, 15), 567.89, false}
  };

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   XSSFCellStyle dateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(14);

   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
   XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Lorem ipsum");
   row = sheet.createRow(1);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("semit dolor");

   int nextRow = 3;
   int nextCol = 0;
   for (Object[] dataRow : data) {
    row = sheet.createRow(nextRow++);
    nextCol = 0;
    for (Object value : dataRow) {
     cell = row.createCell(nextCol++);
     if (value instanceof String) cell.setCellValue((String)value);
     else if (value instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)value);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
     }
     else if (value instanceof Double) cell.setCellValue((Double)value);
     else if (value instanceof Boolean) cell.setCellValue((Boolean)value);
    }
   }

   CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(sheet.getRow(3).getCell(0));
   CellReference bottomRight = new CellReference(sheet.getRow(nextRow-1).getCell(3));
   AreaReference tableArea = workbook.getCreationHelper().createAreaReference(topLeft, bottomRight);
   XSSFTable dataTable = sheet.createTable(tableArea);
   //dataTable.setName("Table1");
   dataTable.setDisplayName("Table1");

   //this styles the table as Excel would do per default
   dataTable.getCTTable().addNewTableStyleInfo();
   XSSFTableStyleInfo style = (XSSFTableStyleInfo)dataTable.getStyle();
   style.setName("TableStyleMedium2");
   style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
   style.setShowRowStripes(true);

   //this sets auto filters
   dataTable.getCTTable().addNewAutoFilter().setRef(tableArea.formatAsString());

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```